# Cannot overline a word inside a verbatim block

Tags: verbatim, bar

I am trying to a overline a word inside a verbatim block but it does not work, for example:

```
\begin{verbatim}
Hwy3 =1  Hwy3   
Hooterville = 0  \overline{Hooterville}
\end{verbatim}
```

I have also tried `\bar{}` but i get the same problem. Anyone has a solution please?

Comment: You can never do any (simple?) customization to words inside `\verbatim`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `listings` package, one can escape stuff in which latex commands should be recognised:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},   
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
Hwy3 =1  Hwy3   
Hooterville = 0  (*@$\overline{Hooterville}$@*)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]