# Overlining text in listing environment without changing the font

Tags: listings, verbatim, minted, overline

In short, I would like to place a line over some characters in a listing environment.

I am aware of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/483947/34551), but am trying to achieve something a bit different.

The following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstset{%
    escapeinside={(*}{*)},%
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily,% 
                       language=Java,%
                       keywordstyle = \color{blue}]
        class new (*$\overline{new}$*)
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

produces:
[image]

What can I do to make sure listing treats the overlined "new" as a keyword and apply the keyword style to it?

I would be accepting a solution that uses minted if it exists.

Comment: Should the overline be rendered in blue as well, or just the word "new"? Please advise.

Comment: I was thinking just the word "new", but both I'm interested in either solution (the color was just an example, the style I am actually interested in now uses emphasis and bold for keywords).